# Applying prior year federal refund to prior year owed tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

If I were due a federal refund in 2011 and owed in 2012 and did not file either year, can I apply the 2011 refund to the 2012 bill? I know I can no longer claim the refund for 2011. Will the IRS handle this automatically?

In reality, there were 2 years I was due a refund and a year I will owe a substantial amount.

I am using FreeTaxUSA to prepare the prior year returns. They have an option to apply the refund to next years taxes, but I don't see any difference in the 1040 that's being created.

Comment: Interesting question, it doesn't really seem fair that they can call your refund forfeited but still collect on other years, but I don't see anything to suggest that's not how it works.

Comment: I would expect that "being unable to claim the refund" means you cannot claim it in any form, neither as a direct payment to you nor as a credit on another return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can apply refunds due that are outside the statute of limitations to years where taxes are due. According to the [IRS Tax Topic 153](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc153.html):

> An original return claiming a refund must be filed within 3 years of its due date for a refund to be allowed in most instances. After the expiration of the three-year period, the refund statute prevents the issuance of a refund check and the application of any credits, including overpayments of estimated or withholding taxes, to other tax years that are underpaid.